# IE 8 performing differently when attached to VS2010 vs. Application on server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer

Using IE 8/VS 2010/IIS on Server 2008

Developing a web app in my local instance of VS2010, in testing everything performs 'as expected'; Deployed to Server; testing (also from the same local machine using 'the same' IE 8)

Getting a client side error:"Error: 'JSON' is undefined", referencing a JS file and following line:

```
function getOrderData() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "order.aspx/GetOrderData",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "OrderID": $(".hdnOrdID").val() }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: showDefaultOrderData,
    error: showErrorMessage
});
```

}
I believe the error message is referencing the call to `"JSON.stringify({....` (but could be mistaken...)

Application performs as expected in FireFox.

So, my application works as expected in IE8 when launched from VS2010
and when using FireFox against the server. But IE gives me a client side (js) error only when the call is made to server.

What can make the JSON reference unavailable to IE under these conditions?
[or, what am I missing here?]

Comment: Take IE8 out of compatibility mode and try again.

Comment: Thanks Paul, it was slightly more insidious than just "compatibility mode", but you sent me in the right direction. There is a setting under tools > compatibility view settings that was checked "[]Display **Intranet** sites in Compatibility Mode". With that checked, the compatiblity mode icon didn't even appear for the internal server that I was testing against. Once unchecked, it worked fine. THANKS! [move your comment to an answer so I can give you credit for it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking IE8 out of compatibility mode.

Also, uncheck the "Display Intranet sites in Compatibility Mode" settings under tools (as recommended by O.P.)